# How can I get/set a struct member by offset

Tags: c, struct

*Ignoring padding/alignment issues* and given the following struct, what is best way to get and set the value of member_b without using the member name.

```
struct mystruct {
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
}
struct mystruct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
```

Put another way; How would you express the following in terms of pointers/offsets:

```
s->member_b = 3;
printf("%i",s->member_b);
```

My guess is to

- calculate the offset by finding the sizeof the member_a (`int`)
- cast the struct to a single word pointer type (`char`?)
- create an `int` pointer and set the address (to `*charpointer + offset`?)
- use my `int` pointer to set the memory contents

but I get a bit confused about casting to a char type or if something like `memset` is more apropriate or if generally i'm aproching this totally wrong.

Cheers for any help

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm bridging a gap between a scripting environment and C-extensions, (think Python C-Types), and I'm defining and accessing structs at runtime.

Comment: Then you are generating C code?  In that case, you can generate C code to access struct members too.  Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The approach you've outlined is roughly correct, although you should use `offsetof` instead of attempting to figure out the offset on your own. I'm not sure why you mention `memset` -- it sets the contents of a block to a specified value, which seems quite unrelated to the question at hand.

Here's some code to demonstrate how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct x {
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
} x;

int main() { 
    x *s = malloc(sizeof(x));
    char *base;
    size_t offset;
    int *b;

    // initialize both members to known values
    s->member_a = 1;
    s->member_b = 2;

    // get base address
    base = (char *)s;

    // and the offset to member_b
    offset = offsetof(x, member_b);

    // Compute address of member_b
    b = (int *)(base+offset);

    // write to member_b via our pointer
    *b = 10;

    // print out via name, to show it was changed to new value.
    printf("%d\n", s->member_b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, memset was just an passing thought since it was just another way of writing memory at an address, It was more of a "don't hold me to my method - I'm open to doing it a different way" comment :)

The offset is actaully the one part I'm fine with, it's how to actually offset a void pointer I think I'm struggling with.... is it suitable to cast my struct pointer to char* for instance?

Comment: Or: `((struct mystruct *)p)->member_b = 3;`

Comment: Is the `(char*)` cast needed because of memory (mis)alignment?

Answer (score 32):

The full technique:

1. Get the offset using offsetof:

   > b_offset = offsetof(struct mystruct, member_b);
2. Get the address of your structure as a char * pointer.

   > char *sc = (char *)s;
3. Add the add the offset to the structure address, cast the value to a pointer to the appropriate type and dereference:

   > *(int *)(sc + b_offset)

Comment: +1 for portable method [link](http://www.safercode.com/blog/2009/05/05/find-element-offset-structure-c-offsetof.html)

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring padding and alignment, as you said...

If the elements you're pointing to are entirely of a single type, as in your example, you can just cast the structure to the desired type and treat it as an array:

```
printf("%i", ((int *)(&s))[1]);
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the array, and getting a sneaky shortcut :)
unfortunately my structs can contain different types

Answer (score 4):

It's possible calculate the offset based on the struct and NULL as reference pointer 
e.g " **&(((type *)0)->field)**"

Example:

```
struct my_struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int *m;
    int *h;
};
int main()
{
    printf("offset %d\n", (int) &((((struct my_struct*)0)->h)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to C so I find this amazing, but how does it work? Why can you access h from that casted null pointer?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, you can address it by `*((int *) ((char *) s + sizeof(int)))`. I'm not sure why you want that, so I'm assuming didactic purposes, therefore the explanation follows.

The bit of code translates as: take the memory starting at address s and treat it as memory pointing to `char`. To that address, add `sizeof(int)` `char`-chunks - you will get a new address. Take the value that the address thus created and treat it as an `int`.

Note that writing `*(s + sizeof(int))` would give the address at `s` plus `sizeof(int)` sizeof(mystruct) chunks

Edit: as per Andrey's comment, using [offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof):

`*((int *) ((byte *) s + offsetof(struct mystruct, member_b)))`

Edit 2: I replaced all `byte`s with `char`s as `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: Why would you use `byte` and not `char`?  Also `((byte *) s + sizeof(int))` is of type `byte *`, which is the same as `char *`, so dereferencing it will (may) not give you an `int` - if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`.  You need a cast to `int *` before dereferencing.

Comment: Correct, partially - your example is more didactic. I've used byte because I feel it has more didactic meaning. Note however, that sizeof(byte) might not be equal to sizeof(char), depending on the architecture.

Comment: Not correct. In ordert to access the `member_b` field you have to add `offsetof(mystruct, member_b)` which is not necessarily the same as `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: And what is `byte`? The C standard doesn't define it.  Also, if `sizeof(byte) != sizeof(char)`, then you definitely want `char` and not `byte` in your code since `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: AndreyT: I did allow this to ignore padding issues so sizeof/offset can be considered same.

Laura: thanks that did it for me!

Comment: @AndreyT: I agree, `offsetof` is better, I was trying to "correct" laura's code without changing its form (I know even then it's not correct).

Comment: @ozone: `sizeof`/`offsetof` cannot be coinsidered "the same" in this case regardless of what you allowed.

Comment: @Alok: actually the C standard does define "byte" -- it's the amount of storage needed for one `char`. IOW, as far as C (and C++) care, 'byte' and 'char' are virtually interchangeable terms.

Comment: @laura, not correct even now.  You want `offsetof(struct mystruct, member_b)`, or better: `((struct mystruct *)s)->member_b = 3;`

Comment: @Jerry, not as a type though.  Without a `typedef`, the cast `(byte *)` doesn't mean anything in C.

Comment: @Alok, I think he wanted to avoid using `((struct mystruct *)s)->member_b = 3;`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your comments that what you're really doing is packing and unpacking a bunch of disparate data types into a single block of memory.  While you *can* get away with doing that with direct pointer casts, as most of the other answers have suggested:

```
void set_int(void *block, size_t offset, int val)
{
    char *p = block;

    *(int *)(p + offset) = val;
}

int get_int(void *block, size_t offset)
{
    char *p = block;

    return *(int *)(p + offset);
}
```

The problem is that this is non-portable.  There's no general way to ensure that the types are stored within your block with the correct alignment, and some architectures simply cannot do loads or stores to unaligned addresses.  In the special case where the layout of your block is defined by a declared structure, it will be OK, because the struct layout will include the necessary padding to ensure the right alignment.  However since you can't access the members by name, it sounds like this isn't actually what you're doing.

To do this portably, you need to use `memcpy`:

```
void set_int(void *block, size_t offset, int val)
{
    char *p = block;

    memcpy(p + offset, &val, sizeof val);
}

int get_int(void *block, size_t offset)
{
    char *p = block;
    int val;

    memcpy(&val, p + offset, sizeof val);
    return val;
}
```

(similar for the other types).