# set member of array to zero

Tags: c++, bit

Morning, 
I hope somebody is here
suppose I have the following structure or even better an array of structures

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  char b[10];
  char c;
};

struct foo* bar;
bar = (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo)*10);
memset(bar, -1, sizeof(struct foo)*10);
```

instead of

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter)
      memset(bar[counter],0,sizeof(char)*10);
```

how to a set b member to 0 in all array of char / b member in all array?

basically my question is a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043871/how-can-i-get-set-a-struct-member-by-offset) one

Comment: `sizeof(char)*8`? Why? Where did `8` come from?

Comment: sorry, yes 10 it's just my mistake

Comment: You seem to be coding in C. Make your life easier and use C++, e.g. `std::vector<foo>`. Then you won't have to play any `malloc` and `memset` shenanigans.

Comment: OP please clarify whether using C or C++

Comment: If you use C, then use `calloc()`, it's like `malloc()` but takes care of the math to determine the right size and it zeroes the memory for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `b` member of each array element to zero by setting the `b` member of each array element to zero. You were almost there, but:

1. You only wanted to zero the `b` member.
2. The thing you're zeroing isn't 8 bytes long.

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter)
    memset(bar[counter].b, 0, sizeof bar[counter].b);
```

Comment: yes I want to set only .b to different value. So I am looking for faster way like just they did

Comment: but is there a method by using offset to initialise all .b without any for loop

Comment: It might be answer that then we use memset we specify the range of memory which should be clear out to a given value so that it might corrupt entire memory

Comment: @IurieCojocari No.

Comment: Sorry for pouting, does it mean it might be possible to solve this problem  by memset(bar, 0, offsetOfb + structureAndress)?

Comment: @IurieCojocari No.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that rather than using a C-style array of `int b[10];` that you use `std::array<char,10> b;` instead.

Then you can fill it with zeros this way: `b.fill(0);`.
If you need to pass the address of the storage to a C-style function you can do that using `b.data()`.
And of course, you can still access its content using `b[i]`, but if you want more safety, use `b.at(i)`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: thank you,  but i actually i am looking to get it done in c style

Comment: @IurieCojocari Then why did you tag your question C++ and not C?

Comment: i was a my typo, but both solution is good. Thank you for spending time to read and to answer